# Amazon SES - SMTP Error Status Code 403: SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

I created amazon trail account to test SES SMTP service, but i got following error

```
{ [SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.


The Canonical String for this request should have been
'POST
/
host:email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
x-amz-content-sha256:72ac6f1d5dc1a4218fc4076dea3277a8a676b15e2c5143229cb3503465817440
x-amz-date:20160912T084424Z

host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date
72ac6f1d5dc1a4218fc4076dea3277a8a676b15e2c5143229cb3503465817440'

The String-to-Sign should have been
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20160912T084424Z
20160912/us-west-2/ses/aws4_request
a1b9fe2e23bbd4456f9b2a8f4115bd84571b8ccbbf9612d2e6b9d330ca6975a7'
]
  message: 'The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.\n\nThe Canonical String for this request should have been\n\'POST\n/\n\nhost:email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com\nx
-amz-content-sha256:72ac6f1d5dc1a4218fc4076dea3277a8a676b15e2c5143229cb3503465817440\nx-amz-date:20160912T084424Z\n\nhost;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-d
ate\n72ac6f1d5dc1a4218fc4076dea3277a8a676b15e2c5143229cb3503465817440\'\n\nThe String-to-Sign should have been\n\'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n20160912T084424Z\n
20160912/us-west-2/ses/aws4_request\na1b9fe2e23bbd4456f9b2a8f4115bd84571b8ccbbf9612d2e6b9d330ca6975a7\'\n',
  code: 'SignatureDoesNotMatch',
  time: Mon Sep 12 2016 14:14:27 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
  requestId: '1cc26156-78c5-11e6-8397-a55641b47b84',
  statusCode: 403,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 55.79463441390544 }
```

Here is the NodeJS script, that i am using

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var ses = new aws.SES({
    'accessKeyId': 'KEY',
    'secretAccessKey': 'SECRET',
    'region': 'REGION'
});
var eparam = {
    Destination: {
        ToAddresses: ['mirXXXX@gmail.com']
    },
    Message: {
        Body: {
            Html: {
                Data: '<p>Hello, this is a test email!</p>'
            },
            Text: {
                Data: 'Hello, this is a test email!'
            }
        },
        Subject: {
            Data: 'SES email test'
        }
    },
    Source: 'mirXXXX@outlook.com',
    ReplyToAddresses: ['mirXXXX@outlook.com'],
    ReturnPath: 'mirXXXX@outlook.com'
};

ses.sendEmail(eparam, function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(data);
});
```

Please note:

> emailids mirXXXX@outlook.com and mirXXXX@gamil.com 
>   both are verified. my SES Region is us-west-2

Comment: You need to immediately invalidate these IAM credentials, if they are the real ones, and don't post your secret key online in the future.  Doing this exposes you to potentially serious liability and may allow your account to be compromised.  Hopefully this was an example, but it looks real.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same issue, I ended up using a SMTP setup, similar to this [tutorial](http://gmanolache.com/sending-email-in-node-js-with-amazon-ses-in-less-than-10-minutes/), and downgraded to from 2.6 -> 0.7.1 to get my mail to send.  There is some sort of configuration issue somewhere that isn't documented well enough to be found after two days of specific google searches.